# Cannot reset fields after a postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-ajax

i'm using a javascript function to reset some fields in my .aspx webpage.It does work when the page is loaded the first time but after a postback it doesn't work at all.

Can someone please give me an explanation ?

Thanx

Answer (score 1):

I see you've tagged this as asp.net-ajax, if it is only a partial postback you're doing, then the entire page isn't being reloaded and the javascript functions wont fire.

If this is the case, try using `ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript` to specify which javascript function to call.

Otherwise, code samples would help us answer!

Answer (score 0):

Most likely those field values are set from viewState or the server is overriding the values. A code example would help provide a more concrete explaination. I've managed to [find this article](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article.aspx?ArticleID=65) that might help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
function pageLoad () {
//do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Checkout jQuery if you have not used it.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
    prm.add_pageLoaded(updateWidgets);
});

function updateWidgets() {
    //do your stuff here
}
```